# Is it possible to list running jobs with DRMAA?

Tags: cluster-computing, hpc, drmaa

I was wondering if it is possible to list all running jobs in the resource manager, using the DRMAA library, not just the ones started via DRMAA itself?

That is, getting data similar to what is output by the [squeue command](https://computing.llnl.gov/linux/slurm/squeue.html) for the [SLURM resource manager](https://computing.llnl.gov/linux/slurm).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know, yes, it is, but only for DRMAAv2, which implements listing and job persistence:

https://github.com/troeger/drmaav2-mock/blob/master/drmaa2-list.c

The python-drmaa module does not implement DRMAAv2 yet, but we might start working soon on it:

https://github.com/drmaa-python

If you want to jump in, you're very welcome! ;)

Comment: Yes, `slurm-drmaa` and `python-drmaa` if you need the python part (which I guess you want for galaxy). In that case even some Galaxy code should be very slightly modified too (drmaa.py).

Comment: Just mailed the author of SLURM DRMAA bindings, and he says he will start working on the v2 implementation next month.